# Blackberry Local connection timed out after ~ 120000

Tags: blackberry, java-me, httpconnection

I have the following code which was working fine:

```
HttpConnection request =
    (HttpConnection) Connector.open("https://www.google.com");
// It locks at the following line until an exception is thrown 
int responseCode = request.getResponseCode();
```

All of the sudden it began to block at the getResponseCode() line until an exception is thrown with the following message:

> Local connection timed out after ~ 120000

All is happening in the simulator, and I have MDS enabled.

Comment: In the simulator, can you go to the normal browser app (not your own app) and navigate to https://www.google.com?  Does that succeed?

Comment: same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248548/blackberry-httpconnection-and-query-string

Comment: I think you need to change URL to `https://www.google.com;deviceside=false`